# Why do I have a voltage over the detector even when the emitter is disconnected from the circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, infrared, emitter

I have built this for a school project exactly as per the schematic.

The voltage measured across the detector resistor is 8 V.

However, even with the emitter disconnected,the measured voltage is the same.

The detector is a photodiode. Flipping the voltage polarities and reversing the detector leads has no effect.

I presume the detector is drawing a current independent of the emitter.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

I have been playing with this simple circuit for an hour now.

[image]

Comment: How would we know? We don't have information what detector it is, how much is VCC, what Rd resistance is, and what is current Id or voltage over Rd.

Comment: With unknown/unspecified parts in your circuit, chances are that your detector/photodiode is unfiltered (i.e. sensible to ambient light) and/or your RD is high enough that a minimal current produces a *high enough* voltage across it. Who knows.

Comment: What's the value of Rd, and the part number for the photodiode?

Answer (score 1):

The detector is mostly a infrared photodiode and infrared radiation is available from many sources. It depends on the wavelength and the intensity.

- Please check if you have the IR-diode in reverse polarity, this is important. If you have the diode in flow-direction, then you get a permanent current flow without any possibility of regulation, it works like an ordinary diode.
- An other possibility is the dark-current because of the temperature. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode